# Variable is already defined in class styleable android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app and I keep having a problem with  the R.java generation system. I get an issue saying

```
variable GradientColor_fontVariationSettings is already defined in class styleable
```

I found this in the R.java file:

```
    public static final int GradientColor_fontVariationSettings = 13;
    public static final int GradientColor_fontVariationSettings = 14;
```

It's also in the vectordrawable/R.java file. I've tried deleting it, but it regenerates it every time I build the app. Anyone know the fix for this issue?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.